# how to show the display name instead of username c#

Tags: c#

I am new to web development and .NET too. I have a website written in ASP.NET using C#. How should I display full name of the current user instead of username using sessions? Please help me. Here is the code.

Code behind login page:-

```
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal username = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;
    string userName = username.Identity.Name;

    if (username.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Session["logged"] = userName;
        agentname.Text = Session["logged"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        agentname.Text = "You are not loggd in please logine first ";
    }
    if (Session["logged"] == null)
    {
        agentname.Text = "You are not loggd in please login first ";
    }
    else
    {
        agentname.Text = Session["logged"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, it works. I am assuming you are using windows authentication. Mark it as answer if it works for you, so others would see it and get help from it.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    
string name = UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName + " " + UserPrincipal.Current.Surname;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the Windows.Security.Principals NuGet, and then write this in your code:

```
string name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```